# Why XMLHttpResponse doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which I can't figure out why it didn't work:

```
<script> 
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState===4) {
            alert(request.responseText); 
        }
    }; 
    request.send(null); 

</script> 

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure that I have the file name "textfile.txt" in the same directory as the html file. What I get is only an empty javascript alert but I can't display the text file text.

EDIT: 
I noticed that I get the following error when I viewed the developer tools this error at the request.send(null) line:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/textfile.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: Start by putting your `<script>` inside the `<body>` tags. ...`<body><script>your JavaScript here</script></body>...`

Comment: @LinuxDisciple Changed it but nothing happened

Comment: are you doing this by directly opening a file in browser or is it being opened from a server? If file you can't do ajax

Comment: @charlietfl has a good point, security settings are very different for localhost versus actual web servers. Yep, you nailed it.

Comment: I am opening it from my computer. Not a server

Comment: Chrome won't let you do that because it can't tell the difference between code you wrote and code that you downloaded as part of a website. If what you tried were allowed, JavaScript from other websites would be able to fetch data off of your PC at will, which would not be cool. You need to get a web server. There are free IDEs that will dummy up a web server for you. Eclipse, Visual Studio, Netbeans, etc. will all do this for you and they're all free or have a free version. Get you one.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple so how can I solve this?

Comment: if you want to play with ajax you need to set up a localhost server on your machine. Lots of ways this can be done simply... and easily searched on web how to do it. Or upload it to a host and load it from there

Comment: You could also download Apache or something if you really wanted to get into it, but I'd just use an IDE. I tend to use Visual Studio just because I do other work in there, but if you try several you'll find your own favorite. Here's a link to a walkthrough of hosting your code in an IIS session in Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1zz9df4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Here's Visual Studio Community (the free version of Visual Studio) https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/ I would also check out WebStorm Community https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/

Comment: The single best tool for learning how this stuff works is probably your browser inspector. It will do code completion for you, you can run your code  right away, and you get to mess with live websites. Also, no installation. You don't even have to leave this page. You can replace 'textfile.txt' with 'index.html', copy that JavaScript, and run it on this very page. I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web server, such as Nginx, Apache and IIS and then put your HTML file and textfile.txt in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script> 
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    request.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             alert(this.responseText);
        }
       else  //error handling
       {
        console.log("Error", this.statusText);  
       }
    }; 
    request.send(); 

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```